# How to correctly write a Unicode/UTF-8 String with special characters to a txt file?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm working with some localized resources for my app and I'm having some trouble handling strings with special characters in Python.

**Note**: I've already read the related questions here on SO but I couldn't solve this problem, I didn't just type this question without looking around first

Let's say I'm working on the Turkish resource file and I have the following String:

> çıkardınız

Now, if I copy/paste this String into the notepad it's displayed correctly (Sublime Text shows the text file with this String has a UTF-8 encoding).
I then load the String in the Python console and try to print it to a file, just with:

```
f = open(d + "C:\\somepath\\test.txt", "w")
print("çıkardınız", file=f)
f.close()
```

I get a `UnicodeEncodingError`. I tried using `encode("utf8")` but I got this result in the notepad:

> b'\xc3\xa7\xc4\xb1kard\xc4\xb1n\xc4\xb1z'

Now, I know this is technically the right value of that original string, but I need to print it just like if I pasted it manually into the notepad.
Also, I need a method that will work with Strings without special characters too, like a random word in english.

Sorry for the (probably) not-so-smart question, but I just can't get my head around this thing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I need to print it just like if I pasted it manually into the
>   notepad.

`"çıkardınız".encode("utf8")` will convert the string into byte sequence.
To write a *UTF-8* string as is into file via `print` function pass in the `encoding='utf8'` argument while opening file:

```
f = open(d + "C:\\somepath\\test.txt", "w", encoding='utf8')
print("çıkardınız", file=f)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was focusing on the print function and I completely missed that extra parameter in the open function, my bad